# Add a reaction to a ctx.send message in discord.py

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am making a poll command, the bot will send a ctx message and will say the poll question. I want to make it so when the poll message is sent, the bot adds two reaction, a thumbs up and a thumbs down. I have tried several different ways but non of them work. Here is the code from my latest try (everything is already imported)

```
reactions = ["", ""]

@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def poll(self, ctx, message,*, question):
    poll_msg = f"Poll: {question} -{ctx.author}"
    reply = await self.bot.say(poll_msg)
    for emoji_id in reactions:
        emoji = get(ctx.server.emojis, name=emoji_id)
        await message.add_reaction(reply, emoji or emoji_id)
```

The code is all over the place because I tried putting different solutions together to see if it would work but it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you're operating from some old examples. You should read the [official documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) to find examples of the modern interfaces.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

bot = commands.Bot("!")

reactions = ["", ""]

@bot.command()
async def poll(ctx, *, question):
    m = await ctx.send(f"Poll: {question} -{ctx.author}")
    for name in reactions:
        emoji = get(ctx.guild.emojis, name=name)
        await m.add_reaction(emoji or name)
```

Comment: I put in the code and it worked instantly! Thank you so much!